# Magento 2.1 - Change status and generate invoice automatically after inline payment received

Tags: magento-2.1, invoice, order-status

i have only one  payment method with CB (paybox) and i want to automatically make some actions if  payment return succeed :

- change the order's status to `paid` for example
- generate the invoice associate and send it by mail

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: EDIT : i find the solution myself.
I made an observer which listen to `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` , this way i can have my order ID.
Then i made an helper which update my order, generate and send my invoice.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

For automatic invoice you can write below code in system.xml:

```
<payment_action translate="label">
    <label>Payment Action</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>paygate/authorizenet_source_paymentAction</source_model>
    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</payment_action>
```

and then in config.xml you can add below line:

```
<payment_action>authorize_capture</payment_action>
```

For order status you need to add below code in system.xml:

```
<order_status translate="label">
<label>New Order Status</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_new</source_model>
<sort_order>30</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
```

and in config.xml you need to write:

```
<order_status>processing</order_status>
```